# Is there any way to have two different where clause in one select procedure in Interbase firebird?

Tags: sql, database, select, firebird, interbase

Is there any way to have two different where clause in one select procedure in Interbase firebird?

I created two tables that will support this question. The desired output is that the select procedure will display all data from table SAMPLE_SINGLE even if there is no SINGLE_PK present in table SAMPLE_DOUBLE.

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_SINGLE (   
  SINGLE_PK SMALLINT NOT NULL,   
  SINGLE_NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  SINGLE_AMOUNT SMALLINT,   
  SINGLE_QUANTITY SMALLINT);

CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_DOUBLE (
  DOUBLE_PK SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  SINGLE_PK SMALLINT,
  DOUBLE_QUANTITY SMALLINT);


CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_FROM2TABLES
RETURNS(
  SINGLE_NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  SINGLE_AMOUNT SMALLINT,
  SINGLE_QUANTITY SMALLINT,
  TOTAL_DOUBLE_QUANTITY SMALLINT,
  REMAINING_QUANTITY SMALLINT)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT
      A.SINGLE_NAME,
      A.SINGLE_AMOUNT,
      A.SINGLE_QUANTITY,
      SUM(B.DOUBLE_QUANTITY),
      A.SINGLE_QUANTITY - SUM(B.DOUBLE_QUANTITY)

    FROM SAMPLE_SINGLE A, SAMPLE_DOUBLE B
     WHERE A.SINGLE_PK = B.SINGLE_PK

    GROUP BY
     A.SINGLE_NAME,
      A.SINGLE_AMOUNT,
      A.SINGLE_QUANTITY

    INTO
      :SINGLE_NAME,
      :SINGLE_AMOUNT,
      :SINGLE_QUANTITY,
      :TOTAL_DOUBLE_QUANTITY,
      :REMAINING_QUANTITY
  DO
    BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
    END
END;
```

For this select procedure it will only display data from table SAMPLE_SINGLE that has a SINGLE_PK present in table SAMPLE_DOUBLE because of the

```
FROM SAMPLE_SINGLE A, SAMPLE_DOUBLE B
         WHERE A.SINGLE_PK = B.SINGLE_PK
```

I want also to display data from Table A that is not present in table B.

Here is the Sample Data,

```
Table A (SAMPLE_SINGLE) SINGLE_PK  SINGLE_NAME SINGLE_AMOUNT SINGLE_QUNATITY
                          1          asdf          100            5
                          2          qwer          50             7
Table B (SAMPLE_DOUBLE) DOUBLE_PK  SINGLE_PK DOUBLE_QUANTITY
                          1            1           3
```

My desired output in a select procedure,

```
SINGLE_NAME SINGLE_AMOUNT SINGLE_QUANTITY TOTAL_DOUBLE_QUANTITY RMAINING_QUANTITY
    asdf          100            5               3                   2
    qwer          50             7               0                   7
```

Here is the actual result for the above procedure, because of the WHERE A.SINGLE_PK = B.SINGLE_PK, it will only display the first row

```
SINGLE_NAME SINGLE_AMOUNT SINGLE_QUANTITY TOTAL_DOUBLE_QUANTITY RMAINING_QUANTITY
    asdf          100            5               3                   2
```

Comment: Interbase and Firebird are not the same database system. They have diverged a lot in the past 18 years, so you can't rely on an answer for one to also apply to the other. So choose: Firebird or interbase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use an implicit (SQL-89 style) join, and the equality in the `where` will automatically exclude those rows where there is no row in `B`. Instead you need to use the explicit (SQL-92 style) join, specifically a `left outer join`:

> A LEFT outer join includes all the records from the left set, but only matching records from the right set.

So use:

```
FROM SAMPLE_SINGLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SAMPLE_DOUBLE B ON A.SINGLE_PK = B.SINGLE_PK
```

See also [Joins](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-joins) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.